# How to setup Active Directory for Tableau Server

Tags: active-directory, tableau-api

I have an Active Directory on an AWS EC2 Instance (Windows 2012 R2). I'm in the process of installing Tableau Server 10.0 on another AWS EC2 Instance (Windows 2012 R2). When running the Tableau Server Configuration tool. I'm prompted to enter the domain of the Active Directory

[image]

*Please ignore the Radio Button for Active Directory selection is grayed out for now as I keep trying and reinstalling*

I'm stuck on what to put for the Domain. I know my AD Domain is named "ABCD.loc" but that doesn't seem to authenticate when I try to setup a Tableau Admin user.

Both the Tableau and AD EC2 Instances are on the same Network in AWS.